# Clarification on relative URLs in HTML

Tags: html, form-submit

From my understanding, `"/"` is equivalent to the base page, e.g. if I'm on

```
http://www.somesite.com/somefolder/somepage.php
```

and see `"/"` then

```
"/" = "http://www.somesite.com"
```

in that context. To give a real-life example of my problem, I'm on http://hope.builtbymighty.com/build/directory-office.html and I see

```
<form class="head-search js-head-search" method="post" action="/">
                <label class="meta" for="head-keywords">Search term</label>
                <input type="text" id="head-keywords" name="keywords" placeholder="Search…" />
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form><!-- /.head-search -->
```

and I want that search feature to work on my own site. So I replaced

```
action="/"
```

with

```
action="http://hope.builtbymighty.com/"
```

but that's not working. In fact, http://hope.builtbymighty.com/ doesn't even work when I try to visit that site. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Also, how do you write a relative URL to the current page you're on?

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong. `/` points to the site root, that is `http://www.somesite.com`.

If you want a relative URL to `http://www.somesite.com/a/b/c.html` when you are in `http://www.somesite.com/a/d.html`, simply use `b/c.html`.

Comment: That was a type-o on my part. Sorry.

Comment: this relative path would be correct if you had a slash at the end of the original url.